# How to control native chrome with selenium web browser

Tags: python, selenium

I want to run the default browser, which we normally use for browsing.

I wouldn't want to run it with chrome webdriver.

it would be like opening the default browser pages "Chrome.exe" and not "Chromedriver.exe"

It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You should learn **Chrome DevTool Protocol(CDB)**. [More details are here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/)

It is low-level browser communication protocol. It communicates via WebSocket and you need to learn how to program WS and read CDP API.

Puppeter working in that way, directly communicate with Chrome.
Logic of Webdriver is to standartize some commands across all browsers.

Similarly, Firefox has [**Gecko protocol**](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/remote/cdp/).